# How to bind a JavaFX progressBar to a double value stored in an Object

Tags: java, progress-bar, observable

I'm still learning and I hope you can help me:

I have an Object `myObject` that stores a double value, which represents the percentage progress of a calculation
*(When myObject is inizialized, the value is 0D, and often updated inside myObject itself until it reaches 100D)*.

---

I'd like to **bind** this double value to a **javaFX progressBar**, so that when the value stored in myObject is updated, so the progressBar will.

---

I heard something about **Observer/Observable/Listener**.
Is this what I am looking for? Can someone show me some code so that I can understand?

Thanks!

Comment: this might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107

Answer (score 3):

I know that I am five months late, but I just [had a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614509/javafx-progress-bar-doesnt-update), and during my searching came across your question that nobody else answered. Nobody answered mine either, so I kept digging until I figured it out myself. I assume that if I stumbled over your post looking for an answer, someone else eventually would too, so I wanted to share my answer.

Yes, what you are looking for is an **ObservableDouble**. Assuming that you are able to change myObject to be a double:

```
DoubleProperty barUpdater = new SimpleDoubleProperty(myObject);
```

And, somewhere in your initialize (or wherever you use the bar), **bind** your bar to it:

```
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(barUpdater);
```

Then, when you wish to update your ProgressBar, you can **set** the value of the updater to something else.

```
barUpdater.set(myObject);
```

In doing so, you will update the ObservableDouble that your ProgressBar is listening for, causing it to update it's value.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616046/6680491) for an example of the code in use if you need it.